# Bases of $\mathbb{F}_p^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Let $\mathbb{F}_p$ be a prime field, and let $V=\mathbb{F}_p^2$. Prove:

The number of bases of V is equal to the order of the general linear group $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$

Comment: Hint: change of basis matrices.

Comment: Hint: This is only true when we consider the bases ordered. And a matrix is invertible iff the columns form a basis.

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you explain a bit more

Comment: You can compute them directly. Which part is your problem?

Comment: @DanielFischer Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 5):

Picking any basis as a reference - the standard basis $\mathcal{S} = (e_1,e_2)$ is a natural choice - we have a bijection between the set of bases and the set of invertible matrices by associating each basis $\mathcal{B}$ with the change of basis matrix $P_\mathcal{S}^\mathcal{B}$. An alternative description of the same bijection is the observation that an $n\times n$ matrix is invertible if and only if its columns (or its rows) form a basis of $\mathbb{F}^n$.

We have that bijection between bases and invertible matrices for every finite-dimensional vector space over any field.